# How filter in dax based on another column

Tags: powerbi, dax

Suppose i have two tables table and tableB in power bi

```
"CALCULATE (
    expression, 
    table[column] = value 
)"
```

In the above `DAX` can I use `tableB[column2]` instead of value?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the RELATED() function and both the tables must be joined. Calculate(expression, table[column] = Related(tableB[column2])). you can also use USERELATIONSHIP.